# Doctrine and getting user's friends activities

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

this is my user entity: ( yep, ManyToMany on self parameter )

```
class User extends BaseUser{

    /**
     *@ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="myFriends")
     */
    private $friendsWithMe;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friendsWithMe")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="friends",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $myFriends;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Activity", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $activities;
```

and this is my activity entity:

```
class Activity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="activities")
     */
    private $user;
```

and this is the query I want to execute:

```
SELECT activity.*
FROM activity 
JOIN (SELECT friend_user_id, user_id FROM friends WHERE friends.user_id = 1 OR friends.friend_user_id = 1 ) f 
ON activity.user_id IN (f.user_id,f.friend_user_id)
```

**PROBLEM:**

I am trying to create this query in doctrine2 but I can't get the way how to join on table "friends" - this table doesn't have corresponding entity, it is based on Users.id-to-Users.id relation.

Comment: Can you show us the DQL you have so far so we can help from there?

Comment: well so far I've been using plain SQL, because I couldn't figure DQL for this query at all, but I need objects in response, not fields from database, and that's why I'm trying to change it..